# Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: Hibernate operation: could not execute query

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am using Spring MVC+Spring+Hibernate(JPA annotation) in my project. where i am getting the following problem :

StackTrace :

```
Jul 24, 2015 4:34:34 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/BaseProject] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: Hibernate operation: could not execute query; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [select user0_.USER_ID as USER1_14_, user0_.USER_ADDRESS1 as USER2_14_, user0_.USER_ADDRESS2 as USER3_14_, user0_.USER_ADDRESS3 as USER4_14_, user0_.USER_CITY as USER5_14_, user0_.USER_COUNTRY as USER6_14_, user0_.USER_DESCRIPTION as USER7_14_, user0_.USER_FIRSTNAME as USER8_14_, user0_.USER_LASTNAME as USER9_14_, user0_.USER_NAME as USER10_14_, user0_.USER_PASSWORD as USER11_14_, user0_.USER_POST_CODE as USER12_14_, user0_.USER_ROLE as USER13_14_, user0_.USER_THANA as USER14_14_, user0_.USER_TYPE_ID as USER15_14_ from user_details user0_ where user0_.USER_NAME=? and user0_.USER_PASSWORD=?]; SQL state [null]; error code [17059]; Fail to convert to internal representation; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Fail to convert to internal representation] with root cause
java.sql.SQLException: Fail to convert to internal representation
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:113)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:147)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:209)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.CharCommonAccessor.getInt(CharCommonAccessor.java:135)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl.getInt(OracleResultSetImpl.java:527)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSet.getInt(OracleResultSet.java:1563)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyResultSet.getInt(NewProxyResultSet.java:2573)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.IntegerTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(IntegerTypeDescriptor.java:61)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:64)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:253)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:249)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:229)
    at org.hibernate.type.ManyToOneType.hydrate(ManyToOneType.java:146)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2283)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1527)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1455)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1355)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:611)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:829)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:274)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2533)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2276)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2271)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:452)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:363)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:196)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1268)
    at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:102)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate$33.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:989)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate$33.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:980)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:407)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.executeWithNativeSession(HibernateTemplate.java:375)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.findByNamedQuery(HibernateTemplate.java:980)
    at com.mgh.baseproject.dao.BaseDao.findOne(BaseDao.java:63)
    at com.mgh.baseproject.dao.UserDao.findByUserNameAndPassword(UserDao.java:23)
    at com.mgh.baseproject.service.UserServiceImpl.getByUserNameAndPassword(UserServiceImpl.java:36)
    at com.mgh.baseproject.controllers.LoginController.processSubmit(LoginController.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:743)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:672)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:82)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:919)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:851)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:953)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:855)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:829)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.obtainContent(SiteMeshFilter.java:129)
    at com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.doFilter(SiteMeshFilter.java:77)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:617)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1521)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1478)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)*
```

Comment: I suspect that you have wrong mapping. Column that isnt numeric mapped to `int` field.

Comment: Three things to remember on SO! 1) Format your question well 2) Ask specific problems and be precise 3) Describe what have you tried so far

Comment: i have only @Id field that is numeric.and that also specified as Integer..

Comment: Please show your Hibernate mapping. I think the problem is with the mapping of the user class.

Comment: show your code please?